# Full animation of Hitomis/CircleMenu during intent [android]

Tags: android

i am using [Hitomis/CircleMenu](https://github.com/Hitomis/CircleMenu) for showing social media icons and intent to another activity on onclick.

Its works properly for toasting sub menu values but for intent its working only at the beginning. When the animation starts, activity intent to another one. I want to display the whole animation and then intent to another activity.

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CircleMenu circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

    circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    circleMenu.addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#30A400"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF4B32"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#8A39FF"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF6A00"), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    circleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

                                             @Override
                                             public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                                                 switch (index) {
                                                     case 0:
                                                         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                                                         startActivity(intent);
                                                         break;
                                                     case 1:
                                                         Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                                                         startActivity(intent2);
                                                         break;
                                                     case 2:
                                                         Intent inten3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Jude.class);
                                                         startActivity(inten3);
                                                         break;
                                                     case 3:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings button Clcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         break;
                                                     case 4:
                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                         break;
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }

    );

    circleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onMenuOpened() {
                                                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu Opend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onMenuClosed() {
                                                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 }
                                             }
    );


}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see full animation you need change your code as follows:

**Step 1 : Declare one variable in class**

int selectedIndex;

**Step 2: In MenuSelectedListener save selected index in the variable**

```
 circleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {

                                     @Override
                                     public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                                         selectedIndex=index;  }
                                 }

 );
```

**Step 3 : Handle Menu Close Event**

```
circleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {

                                         @Override
                                         public void onMenuOpened() {

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onMenuClosed() {
                                if(selectedIndex==3)
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThankYouActivity.class));
   // or use Switch case

                                         }
                                     }
  );
```

Hope this will help you
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Editing the answer of: Appeteria**

**Declare one variable in class**

int selectedIndex;

```
mCircleMenu.setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                    switch (index) { /* 0 is for close menu...*/
                        case 0:
                            selectedIndex = 1;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            selectedIndex = 2;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            selectedIndex = 3;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

**...and...**

```
mCircleMenu.setOnMenuStatusChangeListener(new OnMenuStatusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuOpened() {
            selectedIndex = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuClosed() {
            switch (selectedIndex) {
                case 1:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use  Hitomis/CircleMenu -gradle file,Just use cmllibrary it hase source code of Hitomis/CircleMenu and open CircleMenu class and you can change that animation and onclick events.